# How save number from input as bits and not byte?

Tags: assembly, x86, binary, real-time, tasm

As the title says I'm trying to save a number as binary but when I read it from input it takes it as a whole byte.

I am using a variable declared as var dd ? where I am trying to read from input a 32bit binary number and save 8 bits in every byte from the variable. The problem I have is that when I save on the variable, it takes the 1 or the 0 as a whole byte and not one single bit so it's really only saving the first four numbers.

I am using TASM and 32 bit registers.

```
.model small 
.386
.stack 
.data
    var dd ? 
.code  
main PROC
    mov ax,@data 
    mov ds, ax 
    mov si, 0 

    .inp1A:
        cmp si, 32 
        je .ext4
        mov ah, 00h 
        int 16h 
        jmp .modi1A

   .modi1A:
        mov OFFSET numeroA[si], al 
        mov ah, 0Eh 
        mov al, OFFSET numeroA[si] 
        mov bh, 00h 
        int 10h 
        inc si
        jmp .inp1A
    .ext4:
       .exit
main ENDP
```

This is how I am trying to save the number but in reality its saving each as byte and not bits. I should also get the input using the interruption 16h

Comment: It's not clear to me exactly what you're trying to do. Do you mean that you want to read 32 `'0'` and `'1'` characters from the keyboard, and turn those into a 32-bit value? If so, it seems like `sub`, `shl`, `or` would do.

Comment: Ok il try with addressing then, Im just not sure how to use it. But yes that is what I want that every 0 and 1 represents a bit not a byte.

Comment: If you're not familiar with [bitwise logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation) you should take some time to learn it, since it's a pretty common class of operations in assembly code.

Answer (score 0):

Modern computers are byte addressable at best. So the minimum amount of data you can load is a byte. That's why your 0s and 1s are considered 0000 0000 & 0000 0001. If you want to access bits inside a byte, you need to load the entire byte and you bitwise logic like AND, OR, NOT etc. to make your desired changes.

For example,
you need 5th bit of a value(byte) to change to 0.
You have to do:

```
  mov al, byte [memory_address_of_the_value]
  and al, 00010000b ;or you can give 0x10/16
  mov byte [memory_address_of_the_value], al
```